# stopping/clearing IntentService queue when Internet is down?

Tags: android

I'm loading an array of files to be downloaded and i'm starting an IntentService for each of those files. The problem is in the case of Internet connection problems such as if the device is disconnected I will have to somehow clear or stop the IntentService's queue processing.

In my code I have a while loop in which the file is being downloaded. One of the conditions for this loop to run is: checking for Internet Connectivity which I have done using the following code:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if(cm != null){
             return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
         }
         return false;


 }
```

my loop is similiar to the following:

```
while(.. , isOnline()){
    /// Download file
}
```

If I'm now downloading a file in the queue and if the Internet goes down the loop will not run anymore and the IntentService for that file will stop but now if the internet comes back the download will start from the next file in the queue ignoring the last file which we couldn't download. How can I clear the IntentService queue or make the IntentService queue resume the download from where it left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I clear the IntentService queue or make the IntentService queue resume the download from where it left.

You can't really do either, AFAIK. The queue used by `IntentService` is not exposed to the developer.

In this case, you may be better served creating your own queue (e.g., `LinkedBlockingQueue`), your own thread monitoring that queue, and your own `Service` wrapping up all of that (and handling the case where, once the queue empties, you call `stopSelf()` and exit the background thread).

Or, have the `IntentService` notify something (e.g., via a `Messenger`) about the failed download, so you can enqueue that file sometime later once Internet access returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give me a reference link to the IntentService's implementation in the Android platform as I can't seem to find it anywhere!!!!

Comment: http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java

Comment: So I'm contemplating here, this LinkedBlockQueue will contain Threads and this Queue will be controlled by a 'supreme' thread all this wrapped as u said inside a Service class. So now if i have 10 files i need to start 10 threads stored in this queue and controlled be the supreme thread the will run sequentially. If a thread detects that the internet is down the supreme thread will be informed and the supreme thread will keep a record of the downloaded files using SharedPreferences and terminate itself and clear the queue.

Comment: @user967232: "this Queue will be controlled by a 'supreme' thread all this wrapped as u said inside a Service class" -- more likely this is just the main application thread, responding to `onStartCommand()`. "So now if i have 10 files i need to start 10 threads stored in this queue and controlled be the supreme thread the will run sequentially." -- or have one thread working the queue. Or two. Or three.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how IntentService works and then I can implement a similar service with my own features. Specifically, I dont' understand the part with the ServiceHandler and the stopSelf() call. Then I don't understand how this all fits together to support many intents waiting to be executed, if someone can enlighten me on this!!